# Generate ctags for gVim to replace visual-studio intellisense

Tags: vim, visual-studio, ctags

I am trying to generate ctags to use within gVim that would allow me to get the same kind of experience I get while using visual studio.

My problem is that when I generate ctags inside my project, there are a lot of functions that will not be found by vim.

For example I am working on a DirectX project and when I try to go to the definition of a DirectX function such as "D3D12CreateDevice" I expect vim to jump to the function declaration inside "d3d12.h". However since "d3d12.h" is located in a completely different folder, a tag is not generated for it and vim throws an error saying it can't find it.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your project in one folder, you may use :

```
ctags -R -f /path/to/output/tagfile /path/to/project
```

And in Vim use the tags by :

```
:set tags=/path/to/output/tagfile
```

There are solutions using plugins that can help solve complex
situations. See the references below.

- [Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation)
  Describes using the plugins of Indexer and Project.
- [Navigate code like a pro with Ctags](https://ricostacruz.com/til/navigate-code-with-ctags)
  Describes using [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/),
  an improved version of ctags.